# How to filter data using select (dropdown) in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have object which contains some festival offers. I have given my code below. I am new to this technology. Here, I want to filter `ng-repeat` values using dropdown(select).

Example:
In select if I select all, it should show all coupons(which is available). Which means if I select all it should show get 50% lunch, dinner damaka, supper festival.

Example 2:
In select if I select get 50% lunch, it should only get 50% lunch here. It should show two data: one is storeid: "886745", storeid: "777755".

Based on selection, it should show my code any one help me out.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.isCouponActivated = function(storeId){
    var isCouponActivated = false;
        angular.forEach($scope.activatedcoupons, function(coupon){
        if(coupon.storeid == storeId)
        {
            isCouponActivated = true;
        }
        });
        return isCouponActivated;
    }

    $scope.coupons = [{

        id: "1",
        storeid: "986745",
        couponname: "healthy breakfast offer",
        offermessage: "50% offer for break fast",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    }, {
         id: "2",
        storeid: "886745",
        couponname: "get 50% lunch",
        offermessage: "50% offer for Lunch",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    }, {
         id: "3",
        storeid: "690745",
        couponname: "dinner damaka",
        offermessage: "50% offer for dinner",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    },
    {
         id: "4",
         storeid: "550745",
        couponname: "supper festiwal",
        offermessage: "80% offer for supper",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    },
    
    {
         id: "5",
         storeid: "690733",
        couponname: "eve damaka snaks",
        offermessage: "20% offer for snaks",
        noofcoupon: "10",
    },
    {
         id: "6",
        storeid: "777755",
        couponname: "get 50% lunch",
        offermessage: "50% offer for Lunch",
        noofcoupon: "50"
    }

    ]
    
     $scope.activatedcoupons = [{

       id: "1",
        storeid: "986745",
        couponname: "healthy breakfast offer",
        offermessage: "50% offer for break fast",
        noofcoupon: "10",
    }, {
         id: "2",
         storeid: "690733",
        couponname: "eve damaka snaks",
        offermessage: "20% offer for snaks",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    }

    ]
    
 $scope.activate = function(id) {
 console.log(id);
 }
    
})
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <label>List Of Coupons</label>
        <br>
        <label for="singleSelect"> select: </label><br>
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
 <option value="0">all</option>
      <option value="healthy breakfast offer">healthy breakfast offer</option>
      <option value="get 50% lunch">get 50% lunch</option>
   <option value="dinner damaka">dinner damaka</option>
   <option value="supper festiwal">supper festiwal</option>
   <option value="eve damaka snaks">eve damaka snaks</option>
    </select><br>
  <span ng-bind="searchsubject"></span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div ng-repeat="coupon in coupons | filter:search" data-ng-hide="isCouponActivated(coupon.storeid)" style="border-radius:5px;background: #8AC007;padding: 20px;">
            <br>{{coupon.couponname}}
            <br>
            <br>{{coupon.offermessage}}
            
         <a class="tab-item" ng-click="activate(coupon.id)" id="appcolor">
      <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled" ></i> 
      Activate
    </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <BR>
    <BR>
</div>
```

my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/qwdvdv55/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your select model to be just singleSelect and updated your ng-repeat filter to filter based upon singleSelect.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <label>List Of Coupons</label>
    <br>
    <label for="singleSelect"> select: </label><br>
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="singleSelect">
    <option value="">all</option>
    <option value="healthy breakfast offer">healthy breakfast offer</option>
    <option value="get 50% lunch">get 50% lunch</option>
    <option value="dinner damaka">dinner damaka</option>
    <option value="supper festiwal">supper festiwal</option>
    <option value="eve damaka snaks">eve damaka snaks</option>
</select>
        <br>
    <span ng-bind="searchsubject"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="coupon in coupons | filter:singleSelect" data-ng-hide="isCouponActivated(coupon.storeid)" style="border-radius:5px;background: #8AC007;padding: 20px;">
        <br>{{coupon.couponname}}
        <br>
        <br>{{coupon.offermessage}}

     <a class="tab-item" ng-click="activate(coupon.id)" id="appcolor">
  <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled" ></i> 
  Activate
</a>
    </div>
</div>
<BR>
<BR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="coupon in coupons | 
     filter:data.singleSelect" data-ng-hide="isCouponActivated(coupon.storeid)" 
     style="border-radius:5px;background: #8AC007;padding: 20px;">
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnehy65e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option without changing your code is to implement the search() method referenced in your filter. Implementing a search method gives you the ability to customize the search. You can view it [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwdvdv55/5/).

The search method will be called on each coupon. Return true to show it in the filter, or false to not show it.

```
$scope.search = function (coupon, index, coupons) {
    //if the search combobox value isn't defined, or if it's "all"
    if (!$scope.data || !$scope.data.singleSelect || $scope.data.singleSelect == "0")
        return true;

    if (coupon.couponname == $scope.data.singleSelect) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```